# Mount remote https volumes over https from command line

Tags: https, automount

My mailprovider (mail.com) offers free storage space. I would like to mount the storage in `/etc/fstab` on Linux, so that the storage comes up on boot.

It seems to be possible to mount the volume in windows (`Map network drive`) and MacOs (`Connect to server..`)

Which command should be invoked in `/etc/fstab` to automount the volume?
The storage address is 'https://storage-file-us.mail.com'

Comment: The protocol is probably WebDav https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebDAV_software and you might take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20028/48232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instal `davfs`
2. Put to fstab something like: `https://<URL> <path to mount> davfs
   _netdev,defaults 0 0`
3. Put to `/etc/davfs2/secrets` line like `<path to mount> <webdav
   login> <webdav password>`
4. Try to mount with command: `mount <path to mount>`